# Setup.py Exporting Under a Different Name

Tags: python, setuptools

I have a situation where I need to put all of my scripts inside of a subfolder
in the base directory

## Current Structure

If I have the following document structure

```
superhero

    setup.py
    scripts.py

    heros
        superman.py
        batman.py

    modules
        __init__.py

        fly
            fly.py
        spy
            spy.py
```

And I wanted to export the modules directory under the name superhero,
In the setup.py script, I tried doing:

```
setup(
    ...

    packages=["superhero"],
    package_dir={
        'superhero': 'modules'
    },

    ...)
```

and then running

```
pip install --editable .
```

In that directory. Instead of getting the module installed under the name
superhero, I get it installed under the name modules. So in python

```
> import superhero
ERROR:

> import modules
>
```

## Question

How would I restructure my `setup.py` file so that I could run 
`import superhero` to import all of my modules under a package called 
`superhero`? I couldn't figure this out from the docs.